# CLI read star(*) character fail

Tags: java, apache, command-line-interface

I'm using the apache commons-cli to read my arguments from the console.

Unfortunatly I'm also trying or better to say my application also needs to accept the * charackter.
Everytime I type * as a parameter it reads null or better to say .classpath.

Is there any escape sequence or workaround for the * character?

Answer (score 1):

This is a shell issue, not a java or apache issue: just use single or double quotes around the character: `"*"`, or the backslash: `\*`

Comment: hm ok, thx. I'm then just testing in addition if my argument is \\* equals(\\*) or equals the .classpath :)

Comment: What happens is that the shell expands the `*` to mean "all matching files"; you will get a long argument list that contains all your files. What is the reason that you need to detect the `*` character?

Comment: I was writing an application which reads and displays data from a database. With the parsed arguments from the command line I create my sql-statement/string. So I also have the option to use \* to read all, that you don't need to specify each column to read all data from a table.

Comment: Then I suggest you use `--all` - it's more readable and self-documenting.

Comment: Yeah, this was also my idea when I got stuck at this problem. But my professor doesn't want additional argument options, so I needed to solve it somehow. :) :/

Comment: Keep in mind that your program can accept `*` as-is; it's the operator's responsibility to pass it in without the shell doing its thing. Just do an equality check against `"*"`, and let the human figure it out. Possibly check if the tables given don't correspond to anything, then print a warning message.